# C# WinForm ClickOnce application doesn't work after installation

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, entity-framework, clickonce

The ClickOnce app that I've built installs successfully and displays the login screen of the application. However, it won't go to the main form or anywhere when I submit a valid login info. Could it be this code prohibiting it from going through? The target framework is .Net 4.5 and entity framework 6 is the database layer.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

/// <summary>
/// The main entry point for the application.
/// </summary>
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    bool mutexCreated = true;
    using (Mutex mutex = new Mutex(true, Application.ProductName, out mutexCreated))
    {
        if (mutexCreated)
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            frmLogin loging = new frmLogin();
            Application.Run(loging);

            if (!loging.UserID.Equals(""))
            {
                Application.Run(new frmMainScreen() { UserID = loging.UserID});
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Process current = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
            foreach (Process process in Process.GetProcessesByName(current.ProcessName))
            {
                if (process.Id != current.Id)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Another instance of " + Application.ProductName + " is already running.", Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! The issue was neither to the login nor main form but the entity framework throwing exception on the constructor.

I just followed [this](http://farooqmdotcom.wordpress.com/2013/10/24/entity-framework-6-weirdness/) blog post entry and added:

```
var type = typeof(System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices);
```

to the constructor. Now, it's working like a charm!

Thanks everyone for your response